# How do I show an admob native ad in my App?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, admob

I have a single activity app with a navigation component. On my app, I am trying to implement an AdMob native ad (with a test unitId from google developer docs), but it doesn't show up no matter how much I've tried and I read this [document](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced) but I didn't understand how am I gonna display it with there code. I also tried looking for examples and tutorials but most of them are in languages I don't understand. Any help would be appreciated!.

**My manifast**

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/appId"/> // it is a sample
```

**my_nativead.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_border_style">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ad"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nativeAdSmallImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_email"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nativeAdSmallTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="Ad Title"/>
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView
                    android:id="@+id/nativeAdSmallMedia"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nativeAdSmallName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="Ad description"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nativeAdSmallDesc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="Ad description"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/nativeAdSmallButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:text="visit site"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

**My mainActivity**

```
 frame = findViewById(R.id.myAd)

    MobileAds.initialize(this)
    val adBuilder = AdLoader.Builder(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110") // the unitId is a sample
        .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->

     

             desplayNativeAd(frame, nativeAd)


        }
    adBuilder.build()
}
fun desplayNativeAd(parent: ViewGroup, ad: NativeAd){
    val inflater = parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
            as LayoutInflater
    val adView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.native_small_adview, parent) as NativeAdView

    
    val headlineView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nativeAdSmallTitle)
    headlineView.text = ad.headline
    adView.headlineView = headlineView

    val advertiser = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nativeAdSmallName)
    advertiser.text = ad.advertiser
    adView.advertiserView = advertiser

    val imageAdView = adView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.nativeAdSmallImage)
    Glide.with(this)
        .load(ad.icon)
        .into(imageAdView)

   

    val mediaView = adView.findViewById<MediaView>(R.id.nativeAdSmallMedia)
    adView.mediaView = mediaView

    
    adView.setNativeAd(ad)

    parent.removeAllViews()

    parent.addView(adView)
}
```

**My mainActivity.xml** // i have a lot of xml code on this one but I only showed this, this is a framelyout that spposed to handle the  the native ads

```
 <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myAd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it on my on, I only called the frame layout from my my main fragment instead of my main activity and I wrote the adBuilder with it's function in the fragment's onViewCreated method.

Here is what I wrote..

```
// I wrote it in onViewCreated meathod
     MobileAds.initialize(requireContext())
     
        //native ad
        val adBuilder = AdLoader.Builder(requireContext(), "your_ad_id")
            .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->

                val adView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.native_big_adiew, null) as NativeAdView

                displayBigNativeAd(adView, nativeAd)

                frame.removeAllViews()
                frame.addView(adView)
            }
            .build()
        adBuilder.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
// outside onViewCreated method
      private fun displayBigNativeAd(adView: NativeAdView, ad: NativeAd) {

        val headline = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nativeAdBigTitle)
        headline.text = ad.headline
        adView.headlineView = headline

        val advertiser = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nativeAdBigName)
        advertiser.text = ad.advertiser
        adView.advertiserView = adView

        val icon = adView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.nativeAdBigImage)
        icon.setImageDrawable(ad.icon.drawable)
        adView.iconView = icon

        val mediaView = adView.findViewById<MediaView>(R.id.nativeAdBigMediaView)
        adView.mediaView = mediaView

        val button = adView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.nativeAdBigButton)
        adView.callToActionView = button
        button.setText(ad.store)

        val body = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nativeAdBigDesc)
        body.text = ad.body
        adView.bodyView = body

        val price = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nativeAdBigPrice)
        price.text = ad.price
        adView.priceView = price

        adView.setNativeAd(ad)
    }
```